# Semiregular subgroups of automorphism group of cayley graphs

Tags: permutation-groups, algebraic-graph-theory

Let $\Gamma$ be a Cayley graph over group $K$ and $H$ be a semiregular subgroup of $Aut(\Gamma)$ with two orbits. Then $|K|=2|H|$. Is there any other relation between $H$ and $K$ in general? What about special cases?

Comment: In order to conclude that $|K|=2|H|" you should add WITH TWO ORBITS at the end of your first sentence. Now that your question has changed my earlier answer is not applicable and I have deleted it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you can't say mauch. Take $\Gamma$ to be the complete graph $K_n$. Then $\Gamma$ is a Cayley graph for any group $K$ of order $n$, and any group $H$ of order $n/2$ acts semiregularly on $\Gamma$ with two orbits.

Comment: Ok. Thanks so much. Do you think may be any relation between this two subgroups in special cases? For example for (non-complete)Cayley graphs of order twice a prime?